# How to get native fetch, if it is replaced

Tags: javascript, window, fetch-api

If native fetch is replaced

```js
window.fetch = () => {}
```

How to get the native fetch, if the native fetch is replaced in code that is not my code?

Comment: Store the method in a variable before the external script overriding it is run.

Comment: I posted a dupe. The answer is giving a method to find any native method, not just Array

Comment: @Teemu i cant do that, i think Extensions browser add script tag and replace fetch

Comment: Why not? Just add `const window.fetchOriginal = window.fetch;` as the very first script on the page, then you can use `window.fetchOriginal` anywhere in your own scripts.

Comment: @Teemu bec enemy code run before my and fetch already empty